# rolling updates via tekton pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, tekton

[my helm upgrade tekton task yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gantX.png) I want to do kubernetes rolling update via tekton pipeline with the help of helm-upgrade.Tekton pipeline will be triggered based on the commit to the repo(web-hook configured) & build the dockerimage out of dockerfile present in repo as well as push it to registry. Furthermore, it will get the chart-name from the repo(helm charts present in the repo) & try to do helm-upgrade as the final step.Even after adding the rolling updates config to my manifests, I am stuck at the helm-upgrade step of the pipeline where helm upgrade is failing.
Getting following error-
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition
helm.go:81: [debug] timed out waiting for the condition
UPGRADE FAILED

Comment: Have you leverage the catalog stuff of `tekton` community:
https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/tree/main/task/helm-upgrade-from-repo/0.2

or please paste your yaml for `task` defination.

Comment: thanks for your response, yes, I have leveraged the catalog stuff from tekton community.

Comment: @vincentpli I have pasted the link for my helm upgrade task yaml  above

Comment: Use `kubectl debug pod/<podname>`, to start a debug pod based on your Tekton Task run that failed. Try to reproduce. Check that you can query your cluster API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please, copy/paste your code (yaml) as text not as screenshot